# IIS AppPoolIdentity and file system write access permissions

Tags: asp.net, permissions, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Here's an issue with IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET that I've been researching and getting nowhere with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My question is: using ASP.NET in IIS 7.5, how does IIS and/or the operating system allow the web application to write to a folder like `C:\dump` when running under full trust? How is it that I don't have to explicitly add write access for the application pool user (in this case `ApplicationPoolIdentity`)?

This much I know:

- In IIS 7.5, the default Identity for an Application Pool is `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.
- `ApplicationPoolIdentity` represents a Windows user account called "IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName", which is created when the Application Pool is created, where AppPoolName is the name of the Application Pool.
- The "IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName" user is by default a member of the `IIS_IUSRS` group.
- If you are running under Full Trust, your web application can write to many areas of the file system (excluding folders like `C:\Users`, `C:\Windows`, etc). For example, your application will have access to write to some folders, like, `C:\dump`.
- By default, the `IIS_IUSRS` group is not given read or write access to `C:\dump` (at least not access that is visible through the "Security" tab in Windows Explorer).
- If you deny write access to `IIS_IUSRS`, you will get a SecurityException when trying to write to the folder (as expected).

So, taking all of that into account, how is write access granted to the "IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName" user? The w3wp.exe process runs as this user, so what allows this user to write to a folder it doesn't seem to have explicit access to?

Please note that I understand this was probably done for the sake of convenience, since it would be a pain to grant a user access to every folder it needs to write to if you are running under Full Trust. If you want to limit this access, you can always run the application under Medium Trust. I am interested in finding out about the way the operating system and/or IIS allows these writes to take place, even though there appears to be no explicit file system access granted.

Answer (score 425, accepted):

The `ApplicationPoolIdentity` is assigned membership of the `Users` group as well as the `IIS_IUSRS` group. On first glance this may look somewhat worrying, however the `Users` group has somewhat limited NTFS rights.

For example, if you try and create a folder in the `C:\Windows` folder then you'll find that you can't. The `ApplicationPoolIdentity` still needs to be able to read files from the windows system folders (otherwise how else would the worker process be able to dynamically load essential DLL's).

With regard to your observations about being able to write to your `c:\dump` folder. If you take a look at the permissions in the Advanced Security Settings, you'll see the following:

[image]

See that Special permission being inherited from `c:\`:

[image]

That's the reason your site's `ApplicationPoolIdentity` can read and *write* to that folder. That right is being inherited from the `c:\` drive.

In a shared environment where you possibly have several hundred sites, each with their own application pool and Application Pool Identity, you would store the site folders in a folder or volume that has had the `Users` group removed and the permissions set such that only Administrators and the SYSTEM account have access (with inheritance).

You would then individually assign the requisite permissions each `IIS AppPool\[name]` requires on it's site root folder.

You should also ensure that any folders you create where you store potentially sensitive files or data have the `Users` group removed. You should also make sure that any applications that you install don't store sensitive data in their `c:\program files\[app name]` folders and that they use the user profile folders instead.

So yes, on first glance it looks like the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` has more rights than it should, but it actually has no more rights than it's group membership dictates.

An `ApplicationPoolIdentity`'s group membership can be examined using the SysInternals [Process Explorer tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Find the worker process that is running with the Application Pool Identity you're interested in (you will have to add the `User Name` column to the list of columns to display:

[image]

For example, I have a pool here named `900300` which has an Application Pool Identity of `IIS APPPOOL\900300`. Right clicking on properties for the process and selecting the Security tab we see:

[image]

As we can see `IIS APPPOOL\900300` is a member of the `Users` group.

Comment: @Kev [+1] I posted a similar question regardin NTFS permissions for app pool identities here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232675/applications-apppool-permisions-on-parent-site-folder-structure - I would be grateful if you'd have a look.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer - sorry, I never saw your comment. You still stuck with that question?

Comment: @Kev - yeah, it's become less of an issue as I've been pulled aside to other crap, but it's still unsolved. any thoughts?

Comment: Let's vote to have this section included on MSDN. Never took the time to figure this out, so this is a great help (and I am ashamed I never knew).

Comment: Not clear why this Microsoft IIS core documentation is on SO instead of MSDN.

Comment: I have a question related to this topic. Is there a way to access folder as specific AD user instead of "ApplicationPoolIdentity" ? E.g. if the user named John logs into web app, his AD account is used to access folder on disk. More on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332785/asp-net-access-some-folder-on-file-share-based-on-user-authenticated

Comment: @Primoz - ah...it's so long since I worked with IIS in an AD environment that I've forgotten how that should work. I'll try and jog my memory, can't promise a quick response though.

Comment: @Kev - no hurry, but if you happen to remember I would be grateful.

Comment: @RGS - Apologies, I'm really busy right now. If I get some free time I'll try and answer it.

Comment: @Kev, Please have a look my question shared in the comment and try to provide the solution if you can. I need to complete this activity as soon as possible.

Comment: @Kev what about Multidomain users. This doesn't work when an user from a different domain tries to access the files. He still get unauthorized exception

Answer (score 73):

1. Right click on folder.
2. Click Properties
3. Click Security Tab.  You will see something like this:

[image]

4. Click "Edit..." button in above screen.  You will see something like this:

[image]

5. Click "Add..." button in above screen.  You will see something like this:

[image]

6. Click "Locations..." button in above screen.  You will see something like this.  Now, go to the very of top of this tree structure and select your computer name, then click OK.

[image]

7. Now type "iis apppool\your_apppool_name" and click "Check Names" button.  If the apppool exists, you will see your apppool name in the textbox with underline in it.  Click OK button.

[image]

8. Check/uncheck whatever access you need to grant to the account
9. Click Apply button and then OK.

Comment: Changing the location to the top of the tree structure was the key for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Each application pool in IIs creates its own secure user folder with FULL read/write permission by default under c:\users. Open up your Users folder and see what application pool folders are there, right click, and check their rights for the application pool virtual account assigned. You should see your application pool account added already with read/write access assigned to its root and subfolders.

So that type of file storage access is automatically done and you should be able to write whatever you like there in the app pools user account folders without changing anything. That's why virtual user accounts for each application pool were created.

Comment: This only happens if "Load User Profile" is set to True.

Comment: Thats right, which means the AppPool user's folder wouldn't get created if it wasnt true right? This is why they built it this way.....to prevent IIs from accessing and storing junk in windows/temp and all over the hard drive instead of a managed secure folder just for that account.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this to fix access issues to an IIS website, which manifested as something [like the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752000/iis-file-authorization-failed-for-the-request/59731405) in the Event Logs → Windows → Application:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          1/5/2012 4:12:33 PM
Event ID:      1314
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SALTIIS01

Description:
Event code: 4008 
Event message: File authorization failed for the request. 
Event time: 1/5/2012 4:12:33 PM 
Event time (UTC): 1/6/2012 12:12:33 AM 
Event ID: 349fcb2ec3c24b16a862f6eb9b23dd6c 
Event sequence: 7 
Event occurrence: 3 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/Application/SNCDW-19-129702818025409890 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /Application/SNCDW 
    Application Path: D:\Sites\WCF\Application\SNCDW\ 
    Machine name: SALTIIS01 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 1896 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: iisservice 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://webservicestest/Application/SNCDW/PC.svc 
    Request path: /Application/SNCDW/PC.svc 
    User host address: 10.60.16.79 
    User: js3228 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: iisservice
```

In the end I had to give the Windows `Everyone` group [read access to that folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752000/iis-file-authorization-failed-for-the-request/59731405#59731405) to get it to work properly.