# IIS File authorization failed for the request

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am trying to access a webpage on our local web server. When I browse to the page I get the windows auth challange. Even if i try to enter my credentials it keeps asking again. As you can see from the below error message i am authenticated.

I checked the user account and it has access to the root folder and all lower folders. I get this error message for all sites in IIS

Any advice?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          1/5/2012 4:12:33 PM
Event ID:      1314
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SALTIIS01

Description:
Event code: 4008 
Event message: File authorization failed for the request. 
Event time: 1/5/2012 4:12:33 PM 
Event time (UTC): 1/6/2012 12:12:33 AM 
Event ID: 349fcb2ec3c24b16a862f6eb9b23dd6c 
Event sequence: 7 
Event occurrence: 3 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/Application/SNCDW-19-129702818025409890 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /Application/SNCDW 
    Application Path: D:\Sites\WCF\Application\SNCDW\ 
    Machine name: SALTIIS01 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 1896 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: iisservice 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://webservicestest/Application/SNCDW/PC.svc 
    Request path: /Application/SNCDW/PC.svc 
    User host address: 10.60.16.79 
    User: js3228 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: iisservice
```

Custom event details:

Event Xml:

`<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">1314</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-01-06T00:12:33.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>4189</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>SALTIIS01.intranet.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>4008</Data>
    <Data>File authorization failed for the request.</Data>
    <Data>1/5/2012 4:12:33 PM</Data>
    <Data>1/6/2012 12:12:33 AM</Data>
    <Data>349fcb2ec3c24b16a862f6eb9b23dd6c</Data>
    <Data>7</Data>
    <Data>3</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/Application/SNCDW-19-129702818025409890</Data>
    <Data>Full</Data>
    <Data>/Application/SNCDW</Data>
    <Data>D:\Sites\WCF\Application\SNCDW\</Data>
    <Data>SALTIIS01</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>1896</Data>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>iisservice</Data>
    <Data>http://webservicestest/Application/SNCDW/PC.svc</Data>
    <Data>/Application/SNCDW/PC.svc</Data>
    <Data>10.60.16.79</Data>
    <Data>js3228</Data>
    <Data>True</Data>
    <Data>Negotiate</Data>
    <Data>iisservice</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>`

Comment: @SteveC I think these kind of questions should be allowed because many programmers run into things like this while trying to test and debug their solutions... and sometimes there is no IT department :)

Comment: @ioSamurai thank you. This was an issue I as a developer was having

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure all IIS related users have access, heres some:

- iisservice
- IUSR
- IIS_IUSRS
- Network Service

Also if your using websitepanel be sure to allow its users too.

Answer (score 6):

Give read access to

> IIS AppPool\YourAppPool

on the root folder of the website.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to work until I gave `Everyone` access.

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Select the website folder e.g. `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite`.
3. Right click the file and select "Properties"
4. Select the "Security" tab
5. Click the "Edit" and then "Add" button
6. Click the "Locations" button and make sure you select the *local* machine. (*Not* the Windows domain if the server belongs to one.)
7. "Enter the object names to select:" text box enter `Everyone`.
8. Click the "Check Names" button and click "OK".

Comment: You don't need to grant "Everyone" access.  It can easily be solved by adding local "Users" group.  This [post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5439658/487215) explains how the "Users" is used.  I personally am looking to determine why "Users" is still needed even if I explicitly added read/execute to the local IIS_IUSRS group to the folders/files.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the comment from @J-man (to the "Add Everyone worked for me..." answer) suggesting to add "Users" local machine account ultimately worked for me after following the marked answer's adding of the other local machine accounts.
Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions/5439658#5439658) he provided as well.