# IdentityServer API unauthorized if hosted in IIS

Tags: identityserver4, access-token, endpoint, refresh-token, duende-identity-server

I added additional API to the Duende IdentityServer 6.2 as described [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/apis/add_apis/). Then I tried to access it from a sample App, using typed httpClient using their own library called AccessTokenManagement (aka Identity.Model) pretty much following their [simple example](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Duende.AccessTokenManagement/wiki/web-applications). I use Authorization Code flow, everything pretty much simple and default.

It works well until both server and client are on the same dev machine under localhost. As soon as I publish IdentityServer to IIS, the API stops to work, while the rest still works well (I can be authenticated, and I see in the Fiddler that token exchanges work normally).

The call to API consists from two calls:

1. Calling to `/connect/token` using refresh token. Server returns access token.
2. Calling my endpoint using this new access token.

The flow fails on the step 1. Call to `/connect/token` is already **unauthorized and I can't understand why**. The "good" and "bad" calls looks the same, I cannot see any differences. Previous call moment ago to `/connect/userinfo` consists of the same two steps and it works. Logs on both server and client give no clues.

No reverse proxies, just good plain simple URI. Automatic key management is enabled and the keys are in the SQL table, common for dev and published server. Asp.Net Core Data Protection is enabled and keys are also common.

Relevant parts of logs are below. I noticed that "No endpoint entry found for request path" is specific to IdentityServer and it doesn't actually mean that endpoint was not found. It was found but not processed. I also noticed reacher response headers from bad request and log entry about "Cookie signed-in" in good request but not sure what does it mean and whether it's relevant.

I'm running out of ideas.

Bad response from IIS while trying to get new Access Token:
[image: Bad response from IIS while trying to get new Access Token]

Proper response while developing:
[image: Proper response while developing]

```
///////Relevant part of log for BAD request
|Duende.AccessTokenManagement.OpenIdConnect.UserAccessAccessTokenManagementService|Token for user test@test.com needs refreshing. 
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler|AuthenticationScheme: cookie was successfully authenticated. 
|Duende.AccessTokenManagement.OpenIdConnect.UserTokenEndpointService|refresh token request to: https://auth.mysite.org/connect/token 
|Duende.AccessTokenManagement.OpenIdConnect.UserAccessAccessTokenManagementService|Error refreshing access token. Error = Unauthorized 
|System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IdsService.ClientHandler|Sending HTTP request POST https://auth.mysite.org/mycontroller/myaction 
|System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IdsService.ClientHandler|Received HTTP response headers after 117.7278ms - 401 

 ///////Same part of GOOD request
|Duende.AccessTokenManagement.OpenIdConnect.UserAccessAccessTokenManagementService|Token for user test@test.com needs refreshing. 
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler|AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated. 
|Duende.AccessTokenManagement.OpenIdConnect.UserTokenEndpointService|refresh token request to: https://localhost:5001/connect/token 
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler|AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in. 
|System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IdsService.ClientHandler|Sending HTTP request POST https://localhost:5001/mycontroller/myaction 
|System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IdsService.ClientHandler|Received HTTP response headers after 1994.9611ms - 200

///////Server log during BAD request
Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.EndpointRouter No endpoint entry found for request path: "/mycontroller/myaction"
Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.LocalApiAuthentication.LocalApiAuthenticationHandler HandleAuthenticateAsync called
Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.LocalApiAuthentication.LocalApiAuthenticationHandler AuthenticationScheme: "IdentityServerAccessToken" was not authenticated.
Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.LocalApiAuthentication.LocalApiAuthenticationHandler AuthenticationScheme: "IdentityServerAccessToken" was challenged.
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found it. Thankfully, looked at Fiddler's WebView and had seen familiar picture!

[image: IIS Error Page]

Then, found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279593/401-unauthorized-access-is-denied-due-to-invalid-credentials). The solution was disabling Basic authentication in IIS settings. Access token request has basic authentication header and it seems like IIS intercepts it. Still a bit unclear why other parts of flow worked.