# Set write permission on folder create

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

Hi I have been trying to properly configure IIS 6 to give write permisiosn for about 2 days now and I can't seem to find any good resource on this.I am a bit new to ASP.NET and until now I never had to work with IIS.

What I am trying to do is upload a file to the server.Each user on the server will have his own special folder witch will be created automaticly via C#.Now when I try to upload the file I get this error:

> Access to the path 'D:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\MyWork\Websites\Forum\Images\avatar\userAvatars\aleczandru' is denied

This is my code for creating the folder for each user and saving the file:

```
private void addImageToApp()
{
    string path = "~/Images/avatar/userAvatars/" + User.Identity.Name;

    createPath(path);
    if( Directory.Exists(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path)))
    {
        try {
              UploadImage.SaveAs(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path));
              MultiViewIndex.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
               AvatarDetails.Text = ex.Message;
        }  
    }
}

private void createPath(string path)
{  
    string activeDir = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/avatar/userAvatars");
    if( !Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)) )
    {
        string newPath = Path.Combine(activeDir, User.Identity.Name);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
    }
}
```

All I could find on the internet is that I have to add write permision via folder/properties/security/... while that is all good and fine I can not do this for each folder.

Up  to this point I am not really sure that IIS is the one I need to configure I am a bit lost at this.

What do I have to do to give folders write permisions automaticly on folder create?

And if anyone has a good article or tutorial that shows how to do this please share it with me all the info I could find were very basic.

**EDIT**

I have added the network service account to the Images folder with full permision and have set the application's pool Identity to NetworkService but I still get the same error

**EDIT**

I have messed around with SQL-SERVER for the last couple of days in order to make this work so I might have missconfigured something form what I understand NETWORK SERVICE is stored in SQL-SERVER master.db database.I seem to be having two network service logins may this be the problem?I remember when I first checked it I had none now I have two:

[image]

Comment: As silly as raheel's opening statement, is, he does have this part right: "Now right-click your root images folder, i.e., "Images". Select PROPERTIES. Select SECURITY. Add user NETWORK SERVICE, and give it FULL RIGHTS permissions on the folder." You haven't set the permissions on the Images folder, so you cannot write files, create folders, etc.

Comment: actualy I did this if you check the edit of the post I followed hes instuctions but it did not work

Comment: Yep, I missed that. Sorry. The default that IIS 6 runs under is Network Service. I never bother to modfy the AppPool identity. All I typically do is set the folder permissions. You may need to also check the "write" checkbox for the Images folder properties, though I find that usually the folder permissions are enough.

Comment: I actually added full permision but it still does not work

Comment: Make sure the child objects inherit from the parent, so that your permissions for Network Service are propagated to newly created child folders. If that still doesn't work, double check and then triple check, cause something must have been missed.

Comment: I have checked every folder under images and they all inherit the full control, could another reason be sql-server? Fromwhat I understand the NETWORK USER is stored in the master db I have been messing arround with it for the couple of the days in order to make this work and I seem to be having two NETWORK SERVICE accounts there I will post a print screen

Comment: LOL. Nice catch. Actually its a default setting for any application to be running under NETWORK SERVICE account. So I wrote this just to make sure we are on right track. :-)

Comment: Look, there are 2 types of users you can assign permissions to. First is DOMAIN-level users, and secondly LOCAL users. You need to select NETWORK SERVICE account of your local machine, not the domain. And it has nothing to do with SQL Server at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, when your asp.net application running you can open Task Manager and find process `w3wp`.
W3wp process like any other has user identity (by default - application pool identity - `DefaultAppPool`(like application pool name)).
And if it so, you should add write permissions for user named `DefaultAppPool`. To do it you should open security tab in folder's properties window, then `change`->`add` and type `IIS AppPool/DefaultAppPool` and choose local machine.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions) post should help you!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `IIS`, brother. All you need to do is, open your `IIS`. Go to `Application Pool`. Right click on the Application Pool your website is running with. Select "Advanced Settings" and see the entry made against IDENTITY. Change it to use `NetworkService`. This will mean that you will be running your website under `NETWORK SERVICE` account now on.

Now right-click your root images folder, i.e., "Images". Select `PROPERTIES`. Select `SECURITY`. Add user `NETWORK SERVICE`, and give it `FULL RIGHTS` permissions on the folder.

Now whenever you create a folder and file under this "Images" folder through your code, it will automatically inherit permissions from its parent and you will allow you to do whatever you want (Add/Delete).

I hope this answers your question. If yes, then please mark it as "answered".

Comment: "This has nothing to do with IIS, brother. All you need to do is, open your IIS..." So the first step in the thing that has _nothing_ to do with IIS is to open IIS and change a setting? Nice :)