# Give IIS App Pool permission to write to a directory on a different machine

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm completely lost when it comes to IIS in general, so I am hoping that this is a simple issue one of you all could help me out with:

I have an ASP.NET app running on machine "Foo". Part of its job is to export a text file at the end-user's request into a particular folder.

It just so happens that the output directory needs to be on a different machine, machine "Bar".

So no problem, I say, **I'll just give \FOO\IIS App Pool\DefaultAppPool read/write permission on the specified directory on Bar.
However, I can't seem to change locations to add this user and assign this permission.**

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? This seems like something I should be able to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions

Comment: @Aristos - thanks for your reply! I skimmed that question, but it didn't seem to involve write permissions across different domains :/

Comment: Both domains must have the same user with the same password, and this user must be assigned to the pool. The permissions you give is for sharing only,

Answer (score 0):

Try giving permissions directly to the desired folder to the user that's executing the app pool. (I mean, directly from the OS, out of the IIS)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue.  This was between two machines in the same Active Directory

I performed the following with success:

1. assign both share and ntfs permissions allowing full access to EVERYONE, GUESTS and ANONYMOUS LOGON
2. Open Local Policies Security Options and User Rights Assignment on machine with the share
3. enable policy "Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users"
4. disable policy "Network access: Restrict anonymous access to Named Pipes and Shares"

[I used this as a reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fba2f5f0-9069-48cd-a534-64ce7ba9cc97/windows-2008-r2-domain-how-to-allow-anonymous-access-to-1-folder-share?forum=winserverfiles)

Granted this is setting up this share to be **WIDE OPEN**, use with your eyes wide open.