# IIS 7.5 always returns 404

Tags: .net, windows, iis-7

Using IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2.
Trying to deploy .NET 4.5 websites.  All site files exist in the physical paths and all websites are under 'Default web Site' with the app pool set to ASP.NET v4.0.  Authentication is anonymous. Sites have been converted to applications.  However, when I try to access the sites locally or remotely I get the '404 file not found' error and cannot figure out why.

Note: this server has never hosted any sites before, and we just installed .NET 4.0 & 4.5 before deploying.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Set up the IIS logs to record the Win32 Status code as that may also be useful in debugging the issue.

Comment: I am already logging Win32 - and i didn't find anything unusual.

Comment: So the Win32 is 0 in the log files?  If it isn't, that is a clue to the error.

Comment: if you installed the the framework before the IIS you should do an aspnet_regiis -i anyway it could be the case that the app pool is crashing for some reason, you can try to deploy to a kind of empty /"hello word" app and chack if that runs in the IIS

Comment: Just an idea.. Perhaps you're using the wrong application pool.

Answer (score 3):

The IIS ( concrete the IIS-Worker process) needs the appropriate rights to access the directories. 
Click here for details [IIS AppPoolIdentity and file system write access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions)

You can also run some diagnostic checks in the IIS-console.

Comment: Adding the worker process didn't cure the issue.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you install iis after .net? In this case register your asp.net again. You can do that with your command console.

Comment: No, IIS was installed prior to .net.  Still struggling with this one.

Comment: But the asp site works in iisexpress or the Dev web server? You can try to open a simple HTML file via your iis.