# Why I can't create a file on the Webserver with a ASP.NET Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, process, exe

.NET Application and I want do execute a exe.

To this exe:

*This exe file is a program to show licensed users.*

I test it on my development vm with visual studio 2010 and it works but if i deploy it on the iis7 on my webserver it doens't work. The error is :

> ERROR: Cannot create qrun.inf file

What is the problem? Why can't the application create the file?

Here is my code:

`Web.Config`:

```
...
<setting name="LSDYNA_CMD" serializeAs="String">
        <value>~\\exe\\lstc_qrun.exe -s lwserv-lic -R</value>
      </setting>
...
```

The exe is in my exe folder

Here I get the value:

```
string cmd = Properties.Settings.Default.LSDYNA_CMD;
cmd = Server.MapPath(cmd);

string output = ExecuteCommand(cmd);
...
```

Here is the `ExecuteCommand(..)` method

```
public static string ExecuteCommand(string command)
{
    int exitCode;
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
    Process process;

    try
    {
        processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        using (process = Process.Start(processInfo))
        {
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            exitCode = process.ExitCode;

            return output;
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return "error: " + ex.Message;
   }
}
```

I try it on the web server directly and I get the list (O.o) I opened a cmd and make the command inside this.

I need help I don't know how I can do this :(

Comment: Am I the only one getting nervous when seeing this?

Comment: should be a permission/rights problem. did you try running as administrator?

Comment: What is the path for creation qrun.inf file?

Comment: the path is where the exe file is. ...folder exe --> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\licreader\exe

Comment: can I use the temp folder to create the file?

Comment: @Tarasov You might be Admin but the user that is configured for your AppPool probably not.

Answer (score 0):

set writing permitions on your folder like this: [IIS AppPoolIdentity and file system write access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions)

Or

You may create new folder in your ASP.NET Project and put your exe file there.