# Not valid connection string

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to publish a web application through my local IIS. The database is local access database. I got this error that it is not a valid connection string as below. However, I can't see anything wrong with it.

The value

```
'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\eAdvanceData.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;'
```

is not a valid connection string or an absolute path.

Comment: Did you escape your slashes?

Comment: Does the database file eAdvanceData.mdb reside at c:\Temp\ on both your local machine and the web server you are publishing to?

Comment: Where do you generate that connection string from?  Because it really does seem to be lacking some things.

Comment: How do you get and set the connection string ? Be sure the backslash is not acting as an escape character

Comment: The connection string is in the web.config file and it is double quoted there. I thought the backslash was fine there:                  <add name="EAdvanceLogin"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\eAdvanceData.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;"
        providerName="Microsoft.Data.OLEDB"/>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like IIS doesn't have access to the file.  You have to give read/write access to that file to the Application Pool that your site is running as.

This might help...
[IIS AppPoolIdentity and file system write access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions)

Comment: When I was running Process Explorer, I can't find any process run by Application Pool. Wonder why?