# IIS Application Pool 'Stalling'

Tags: .net, iis, application-pool, aif

I work on a product ([Microsoft AX 2009 + AIF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496452(v=ax.50).aspx)) that publishes it's web service to IIS (ver. 7.0, WinOS 2008 R2), with the requirement for the worker process to run .NET version 2, enable execution in 32 bits, and run as a *proxy* domain account that has access rights to the aforementioned product.

The first few petitions are received, processed and a response is returned correctly.  After sending the same request a fixed number of times however the IIS application appears to 'hang', only responding once more if we manually Recycle the corresponding Application Pool.

We believe that we have the correct directory permissions applied [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions), [2]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2010/03/29/what-changes-are-required-if-we-change-the-business-connector-proxy-used-by-ax-2009-generated-aif-web-services.aspx) and have also tried adding the account to the box Administrators group.

We found the following in the *httperrX.log* where we reapplied the identity account's password, and disabled the application group's error protection:

```
80 HTTP/1.1 GET /MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/CustomerService.svc 503 1 Disabled MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50
```

To 'force' the recycling issue we have limited the available memory, from the default 512MB(?) to 100MB...
[image: IIS Application Group Recycle Parameters]

But this is not ideal, and will suffer from a reduction in performance even though the service is called from a low volume site.
[image: Process Explorer - w3wp.exe]

Could this be a security issue [attempting to access the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885654) or file system?  Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to find in which part the process hangs (make trace). Then analyse what is causing the delay. This could be caused by a lot of different problems.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error,ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="LFFServicesHost.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

  </system.diagnostics>
```