# Application hosted on IIS not able to read some html files placed on the same server in diffenrent folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET application hosted on IIS. And have some html files in a folder under "c" drive on the same server. My application try to read those files and display some content from those files onto the webpage. But it seems like application is not able to read those html files. I have tried with all the permissions.

LIKE : giving that folder "Network service" "Network", "ISUR" full control permissions. But application is displaying

404 File or Folder not found error. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under file Properties > Security > Group or user names > make sure that user IIS_IUSRS has access to the file.

And remember that it's not a good practice to allow webserver to access files on C.
Webserver should be limited to inetpub.

Comment: The problem is I don't see IIS_IUSRS in the group list on my server. My iis_WPG is there. But it has full permissions to it.

Comment: are you completely sure that you are referencing the file with 404 error correctly? Also - check this link out - it may contain answer to your problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions

Comment: What do you mean by referencing the file with 404 error correctly?

Comment: 404 is supplied when the file can't be found. So I was asking if you were sure, that you were referencing it correctly.