# Is not a valid virtual path file from network drive

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Below is my code, and I'm getting following error.Please help..

```
private const string FILEPATH = @"\\**.**.**.**\D:\BCPResult\Cust_File.txt";
string filePath = string.Empty;
filePath = Server.MapPath(FILEPATH);
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

**Error :- \++.++.++.++\D:\BCPResult\Cust_File.txt' is not a valid virtual path.**

Answer (score 0):

Try it in windows explorer:  `start run:  \\**.**.**.**\D:\BCPResult\Cust_File.txt`

It would be `\\**.**\D$\BCPResult\Cust_File.txt`

But if you used that, it's a network path, not a virtual path relative to your site, so you don't need `Server.MapPath()` which would give you:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\**.**\D$\BCPResult\Cust_File.txt
```

Where `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\` is the IIS root (not your application) (it may be different) - this is because the `\\` part resets outside your application root path.  If you do `Server.MapPath("x")` it will be based on the root of your application.

Comment: Now it is saying .Access to the path '\\++.++.++.++\D$\BCPResult\Cust_File.txt' is denied..may be permission issue...how to resolve it .

Comment: By giving permissions...   D$ is a share on the remote server, so will need access through the share as well as directly on the drive.   You'll be better off creating a *new* share on `D:\BCPResult` on the server: Log on the server, right click the folder, properties, sharing, advanced sharing - give read permissions to the account that your app pool uses.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions