# .Net Core 1.0, EntityFramework (SQLite), on IIS, which Windows user to give write permissions to

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, iis, .net-core, user-permissions

I'm stuck with a .Net Core 1.0 project I'm not allowed to update to the newest .Net Core version yet, and currently trying to deploy it to a development IIS (8.5, on Server 2012 R2).

Slowly working through the list of errors now… and I've come across a strange case with an sqlite database the service uses internally.

The project has a postpublish step that grants write permissions (to `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` on the machine running the IIS) for a few files the service needs to be able to write.
All but the sqlite file *are* writeable from the service afterwards, and are correctly being updated.

For the sqlite database however it throws a `SqliteException SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'`, unless I give `Full Access` not only to the `DefaultAppPool` user mentioned above, but `Everybody`—so to me it looks like the EF code is executed in another user context than the rest of the service.

Does anyone know which user, or how I could best find out (or what else might be the problem)?

Comment: In situations like these, I only survive with the help of [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).

Comment: @UweKeim Good idea, yeah, I might give this a try.

Comment: See also [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5437723/107625) regarding the "virtual" `APPPOOL\AppPoolName` user. Or [this one](http://www.active-directory-faq.de/2013/12/berechtigung-der-iis-pool-identitaet-auf-filesystem-ressourcen/) in German.