# Sccess some folder on file share based on user authenticated

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication, impersonation, file-access

I have an asp.net web application with forms authentication and users (credentials) are checked against active directory, username is actually samAccountName attribute from AD.
Now I need to enable users to get access to some files which are located on file share, where each user has his own folder.

First proof of concept works like this:

1. appPool in IIS is configured to run under some domain user, and this user was given R/W access to file share and all user folders
2. when the user logs into web app only content of the folder on the path "\\myFileServer\username" is visible to him. And same when uploading files they get stored to "\\myFileServer\username".

While this works, doesn't seem to be secure at all. First issue is that user under which application pool runs has access to folders from all users. And even bigger concern is that only username determines to which folder you have access.

So my question is what is the correct/better way to doing this ? I was reading about impersonating the user, but this is not advised anymore if I understood correctly ? And I don't have Windows authentications since the web application must be accessible from internet.

Comment: You can use Basic Authentication over https: and impersonate access to file shares.

Comment: Another reason to use forms auth is that we want custom login form not browser prompting for credentials. So we will stay with forms auth as it is. Question remains on how to securely access file system.

Comment: Where did you read that impersonation isn't advised anymore? It seems to be a good fit for this problem.

Comment: I don't know, it's just what I have read, but I can't tell if it's true or why would it be.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not running the application under a user account, but creating an application specific account under which it runs with the proper R/W rights, and separate the person who gives these rights from the development team.

Within the application's authentication: after you receive a GET/POST request, you can verify the path to which the current user would read/write data, and cross-reference this with the path the user is authorized to read/write from. If these are incorrect, return a 401 NOT AUTHORIZED response, else, carry on the operation as you do now.

If your endpoints are protected properly, and the application runs under its own account, I don't see any harm in the setup itself. This still however gives the developers a way, through the application, to indirectly access other user's files. Based on how tight these checks must be, you could add additional controls, (like only allowing the application to connect from the production server, and only allowing server transport in a controlled way).

Comment: I am already running application under specific account something like "svcMyWebApp" which has minimal rights on the system itself.

Comment: I am concerned that some user might after already being logged into web application somehow exploit it and present himself as another user and get access to that user folder. Since the web application has access to all folders on the share and you just limit the user to the correct folder based on his username.

Comment: Is the user name something the users can change themselves? In that case that is indeed dangerous, and you could check if there is a unique identifier for each user which cannot be changed (like an ID)

Comment: Users can not edit their profiles trough web app. I'm just a bit nervous that a service user under which runs appPool can access the fileshare and all the data.
I deem it safer to run appPool under ApplicationPoolIdentity account and to just impersonate logged user when accessing fileshare holding data. So that ntfs permissions would take care if user may or may not access some folder.
Maybe this thinking is wrong, but that is exactly what I wan't to find out :)

Comment: Ah, I now understand better what you mean. I would definitely run the app pool under a dedicated application account as well. What if the user leaves the company? You don't want to have downtime fixing the application. Based on the information you've given, impersonating users seems like a good solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

From the Description of your Problem i think `Custom HttpHandlers` are the right choice for you. You didn't mention what type of files will be present in your Folder , for brevity i will answer by assuming it will be having PDF files.

As you were mentioning that your application will be having different users so for this you need to use .NET built-in authentication manager and role provider. With a simple security framework setup, we'll place a PDF file in the web application, behind a web.config protected folder.then create a custom HTTP handler to restrict access on the static document to only those users who should be allowed to view it.

A sample HTTP Handler:

```
public class FileProtectionHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        switch (context.Request.HttpMethod)
        {
            case "GET":
            {
                // Is the user logged-in?
                if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
                    return;
                }
                string requestedFile = 
                 context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.FilePath);
                // Verify the user has access to the User role.
                if (context.User.IsInRole("User"))
                {
                    SendContentTypeAndFile(context, requestedFile);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Deny access, redirect to error page or back to login 
                     //page.
                    context.Response.Redirect("~/User/AccessDenied.aspx");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Method **SendContentTypeAndFile** :

```
private HttpContext SendContentTypeAndFile(HttpContext context, String strFile)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = GetContentType(strFile);
    context.Response.TransmitFile(strFile);
    context.Response.End();
    return context;
}
private string GetContentType(string filename)
{
    // used to set the encoding for the reponse stream
    string res = null;
    FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(filename);
    if (fileinfo.Exists)
    {
        switch (fileinfo.Extension.Remove(0, 1).ToLower())
        {
            case "pdf":
            {
                res = "application/pdf";
                break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Last step is that you need to configure this HTTP Handler in the webconfig , 
and You can see the more  info [here](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2009/11/11/securing-pdf-files-in-asp-net-with-custom-http-handlers/)

Here is the complete [Source Code](http://www.primaryobjects.com/temp/CustomFileHandlerDemo.zip)

Comment: It's a custom binary file, but i guess that it doesn't matter.

Comment: The files are not stored on the web server, they are stored on fileshare and each user has own folder on this fileshare.
Can you protect this setup with web config ? Also users are added and removed over time, usually 1 or 2 users are added or removed per week.

Answer (score 0):

You're architecture (and assumptions) seem good for a low/mid security level, but if the nature of your data is very sensitive (medical, etc) my biggest concern about security would be controlling the user sessions.

If you're using forms authentication then you're storing the authenticated identity in a cookie or in a token (or if you're using sticky sessions then you're sending the session Id, but for the case it's the same). The problem arises if user B has phisical access to the machine where user A works. If user A leaves it's workplace (for a while or forever) and he doesn't explicitly close it's session in your web app, then his identity has been left around, at least until his cookie/token expires, and user B can use it since the identity system of ASP.NET hasn't performed a SignOut. The problem is even worse if you use tokens for authorization, because in all the infamous Microsoft implementations of the Identity System you're responsible of providing a way to invalidate such tokens (and make them dissapear from the client machine) when the user signs out, since they would stay valid until it's expiration. This can be addressed (but no completely thus not very satisfactorily for high security requirements) issuing short living refresh tokens, but that's another story, and I don't know if it's your case. If you're going with cookies then when user A signs out it's cookie is invalidated and removed from the request/response cicle, so this problem is mitigated. Anyway you should ensure that your users close their sessions in your web app or/and configure the cookies with short lives or short sliding expirations.

Other security concerns may be related with CSRF, wich you can prevent using the Antiforgery Token infrastructure of ASP.NET, but these kind of attacks are methods that are very far away from the tipical user (I don't know anything about the nature of your user and if your app is exposed to public on internet or it's only accesible on an intranet), but If you worry for such specialised attacks and have so sensitive data, maybe you should go with something more complex than forms authentication (two factor, biometrical, etc)