# How do I apply web folder IIS folder permissions using Azure Pipelines during deployment?

Tags: iis, azure-devops, permissions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I successfully used Azure DevOps Pipeline to deploy an AspDotNet Core site to IIS, but IIS Worker Process requires read and write permissions on some of its folders. How do I go about do this?  I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reference to this doc: [Deploy to a Windows Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops) and [Build, test, and deploy .NET Core apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive), we can set up continuous deployment of your ASP.NET app to an IIS web server running on Windows using Azure Pipelines with deployment group.

However, we are sorry to say that it is impossible to grant IIS Worker Process required permissions to this local site using Azure Pipelines, you need to edit your IIS configuration and you could contact IIS support here: https://forums.iis.net/default.aspx/41?IIS+7+and+Above.

BTW, I found this thread: [IIS AppPoolIdentity and file system write access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions), hope it helps.