# IIS restrict access to separate files

Tags: iis

We have an IIS server that has a lot of static HTML files in the folder.
We want to restrict access for users.
For example, one logged-in user has access only to one special file, another user has access to another special file and hasn't access to all other files.
I thought that it can be done via NTFS permissions.
I have added Read-Only access rights for user for a specific file, but another user still has access to the same file.
If I remove IIS_IUSRS group from NTFS permissions - nobody can't open a file from the IIS web page.
So it seems that the IIS_IUSRS group must have access to all folders and files.
But how we can restrict access rights? I also tried to add DENY access for users, but no luck

Comment: This answer [IIS AppPoolIdentity and file system write access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5439658/13336642) gives you some light.

Comment: According to this answer, it seems that it's impossible to restrict access ? Am I right or not?

Comment: It can be done, but you need to configure the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Could you, please, explain how a can configure permissions? Tried many things in NTFS, but no luck...

Comment: Is there anything you don't understand about the content in the above link?

Comment: Sorry. but I don't understand how I can restrict access to files according to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

1. Created an ASP.net Core redirector (needed for my purposes);
2. Published to IIS;
3. Folder with HTML files moved into the IIS site;
4. Converted this folder into Application with Win auth;
5. Changed permissions on each file via PS script (easy than manually) - one file per user.