# Access Denied in IIS 7.5 MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis-7.5

I'm working with an MVC application on a test server that used to work perfectly. It creates accounts on a server that a 2nd application uses for logging in. It uses a credential store and PrincipalContext and UserPrincipal objects to create these accounts.

I haven't used the test version of this app for months or possibly almost a year. Now when I go to create an account with the application, I get the following error:

> Access is denied.
>   ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.

I looked at anonymous access, but the production version of this app also has a rule to deny anonymous access and it's working fine. This application never used impersonation even when it was working and I've heard that granting explicit access to ASP.NET is not generally recommended. I can make the application work locally through Visual Studio, but the version deployed to test continues to give this error. I would rater not republish the site to test, but perhaps that's the only option left? Is there anything obvious (but not to me) that could have changed in the security settings to cause this? I'm still researching with no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: Check your application pool, what user/identity is the appliation pool set to run as?

Comment: The identity is listed as "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

Comment: "ApplicationPoolIdentity" is IIS 7.5 not 7. In IIS 7.5, each application pool has a unique identity. In IIS7 the default identity would have been NetworkService. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267941/iis-7-5-app-pool-identity-permission-not-assigned-to-folder-but-application-sti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a service account to your ApplicationPool Identity that has the appropriate level of access. When you're using the Studio, it uses your user account for access so it's almost a given. When the application is installed onto IIS it uses the lowest possible level of access available, and that simply isn't enough. It isn't recommended that you open it wide up, but establishing a limited access service account for this specific purpose will allow the application to function without having to compromise system or personal accounts.

Comment: Thanks, it was the app pool identity's lack of access.