# App pool identity, Users group and iis isolation

Tags: security, iis, acl, applicationpoolidentity

I followed these two questions:

> [IIS 7.5 App Pool Identity permission not assigned to folder, but application still can write to its folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267941/iis-7-5-app-pool-identity-permission-not-assigned-to-folder-but-application-sti)
>
> [IIS AppPoolIdentity and file system write access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions)

To try to understand how it is possible to isolate IIS `ApplicationPoolIdentity` users although they are members of the `Users` group that has read access practically everywhere.

I think that should be more secure that the `App Pool\myapp` could only read the contents of the site (or read/write its virtual directory), but what is the best practice to do that without removing the `Users` group ACL from everywhere?? my Windows server defaults has the "users" group on the volumes acl with read access and inherits to all folders...

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question beginning with "Is it true that sites and in general...", can you rewrite this. I think your trying to ask: *How do I prevent the application pool identity user from reading data everywhere on the server that the `Users` group has access?* - can you confirm this?

Comment: discard that, yes I confirm :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is also answered in the answer you linked to, by Kev. You should preferably set up your web root on a separate non-system drive. There you can remove the `Users` group from the top level and grant rights to the home folder of each site to the respective application pool identities only.

Answer (score 1):

AMit - that still doesn't solve the issue that his web app can read practically any file on the c:/ drive. But it's even worse than that. The web app can WRITE to the c:/ drive. Because the users group has permission to do so...

It's a fundamental security flaw in Microsoft's design. I've been searching for a solution myself and yet to find one.

Putting the web site on a different partition is security through obscurity... Which is basically no security at all - rather the mere hope that they don't find...